# when i try to go duplicate email check always i have receive error " Attempt to read property "num_rows" on bool in " why is it happen?

Tags: php, database

problem is :

i try below code to get information from database and check that email address is exists or not ?

but when i run in browser i got error "Attempt to read property "num_rows" on bool in  "

```
Query = "SELECT * from customerlogin_tbl where Email=$Email ";
$Result = mysqli_query($con, $Query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($Result) > 0) {

    $error['txtEmail'] = 'Email alrady exists';
}
```

i use this code and i received error below

> Attempt to read property "num_rows" on bool in

i am expecting
that my condition is going work

Comment: You should be using prepared statements to avoid SQL injection, but for what you have `$Email` needs to be in quotes i.e. `$Query = "SELECT * from customerlogin_tbl where Email='$Email'";`

Comment: Please do read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php and rewrite your code to use prepared statements, which will save you from ever having to worry about quoting values again.

Comment: i have tries to do statements but it is not work please suggest how i do write code ,i am working on xampp localhost?

Comment: The answer I linked shows how to do prepared statement using `mysqli`. Give that a try and if you have issues, post a new question. But for now you can just use the fix that I gave in my first comment.